# Downloading video/image/etc. from URL

Tags: node.js, typescript, axios

I am trying to download a file from URL but just cannot get it working, sometimes I get "Maximum call stack size exceeded" with:

```
async function downloadFile(url: string, path: string) {
    const writer = fs.createWriteStream(path),
        response = await axios({
            url,
            method: "GET",
            responseType: "stream"
        });

    response.data.pipe(writer);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        writer.on("finish", resolve);
        writer.on("error", reject);
    });
}
```

other times it downloads but it has 0 byte files...
Also right now I hard code it before request the file type, but how can I know the file type so I can use the correct one with saving the file.
Right now I just use:

```
await downloadFile(req.body.url, join("../tmp/", uuid, "/input.mp4"));
```

Comment: You can use `response.headers['content-type']` to get the requested file type.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const url = "http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/J---aiyznGQ/mqdefault.jpg";
const file = fs.createWriteStream("image.jpg");
const request = http.get(url, function(response) {
  response.pipe(file);
});
```

follow the same approach for all types of files

Comment: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16)

Comment: Do you know a way to fix that?

Comment: Feel so dumb rn, but I had to do url.value and I only imputted url. Thats why it wasnt working.